# Add custom column for custom field

Tags: custom-field, columns

I created a custom field `bookcode` using the code below. So, how I can add a column for this meta data into my post type manager and make it sortable?

```
function save_bookcode( $post_id ) {
    if ( wp_is_post_revision( $post_id ) )
        return;
    // save custom field 'bookcode' as CFX+ID
    add_post_meta( $post_id, 'bookcode', 'CFX' . $post_id, true );
}
add_action( 'save_post', 'save_bookcode' );
```

Comment: That is the name of the post type (or post types) that you'd like to this column to?

Comment: @DaveRomsey my CPT is 'stfic'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I adjusted the code for you. You can directly use the code in **functions.php** file. Here is more reference that can help you to understand more. 
[Link 1](https://code.tutsplus.com/articles/add-a-custom-column-in-posts-and-custom-post-types-admin-screen--wp-24934)
[Link 2](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/manage_posts_custom_column)

```
// Adding Custom Column
add_filter('manage_stfic_posts_columns', 'ST4_columns_head_only_stfic', 10);
add_action('manage_stfic_posts_custom_column', 'ST4_columns_content_only_stfic', 10, 2);

// CREATE TWO FUNCTIONS TO HANDLE THE COLUMN
function ST4_columns_head_only_stfic($defaults) {
    $defaults['bookcode'] = 'Book Code';
    return $defaults;
}
function ST4_columns_content_only_stfic($column_name, $post_ID) {
    if ($column_name == 'bookcode') {

        // Now you have to garb the meta value and show.            
        $book_code = get_post_meta($post_ID,'bookcode',true);
        echo '<span>'.$book_code.'</span>';
    }
}
```

Comment: Ah yes!!! It worked perfect! Now I'll try to learn from this and add rating field into CPT admin. Thank you!!!

Comment: Good to hear that it resolved your issue.